# Migrate memory pages of a running process

Tags: process, migrate, numa

On a NUMA machine, is it possible to migrate memory pages of a running process to one node?

P.S: I know taskset can change the affinity in runtime, but there's no documentation says how the already allocated memory pages are affected.

Numactl can only works when creating process, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

There is such call in the libnuma library (numactl package, since [2003](https://lwn.net/Articles/32848/)): http://linux.die.net/man/3/numa

> ```
> void numa_tonode_memory(void *start, size_t size, int node);
> ```
>
> `numa_tonode_memory()` put memory on a specific node.

It may be implemented with `mbind` call with `MPOL_MF_MOVE` option: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mbind.2.html

> mbind - set memory policy for a memory range
>   If `MPOL_MF_MOVE` is specified in flags, then the kernel will attempt
>          to move all the existing pages in the memory range so that they
>          follow the policy.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/page_migration

> Page migration allows a process to manually relocate the node on which its
>   pages are located through the MF_MOVE and MF_MOVE_ALL options while setting
>   a new memory policy via mbind().

Or with `move_pages`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/move_pages.2.html
"move_pages - move individual pages of a process to another node"